# RSolve with simple initial condition

Tags: recursion, difference-equations, algebra

Suppose we have the following equation:
$$
g_ma_m=r_ma_{m-1}
$$
with initial condition $a_L=d$ and $L$ might be negative.

The following command

```
RSolve[{g[m] a[m] == r[m] a[m - 1], a[-10] == d}, a, m]
```

gives me

```
{{a -> Function[{m}, 
  d*Product[r[1 + K[1]]/g[1 + K[1]], {K[1], 0, -1 + m}]]
}}
```

where `K[1]` runs from 0 to $m-1$. But shouldn't `K[1]` runs from -10 to $m-1$?

Comment: or rather from -10 to m-1 (since the arguments of r[] and g[] are  1+K[1] )? Yes, it should. I think ...

Comment: @Wouter,yes you are right.